# Open react-360 view on click

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, 360-degrees

I'm trying to create a webapplication using react-360. Until now it seemed to be working just fine. But is there a possibility, that the 360-view only opens on a click and not on init? I want to have a menu where the user can choose to start the 360-tour.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this may be what your looking for.

[WebVr Polyfil](https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill)

Implementing this library will allow you to toggle between VR mode and a normal view. Check the following example that I've done (taken from my Udemy course). You have to view it on mobile for it to work.

[Example](http://makeshift-skins.surge.sh)

If this isn't what you're going for, perhaps you're looking for something like this:

[HouseTourVR](http://groovy-sister.surge.sh/)

This is a project that I made that has a welcome index.html and with the click of the enter button takes me to the 360 tour. Hope this is what you're looking for.